# Cycles volumes turn red and glitchy

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics, artifacts

I am trying to make some clouds for a scene. In EEVEE the clouds look just fine, but when I view them in Cycles, they have really weird red artifacting going on. You can see this in the upper left- and right-hand corners of the attached image.[image: Landscape with weird volume artifacts]

Here is a screenshot of my node setup:
[image: Node setup]

And a screenshot of the relevant render settings:
[image: Render settings]

More information:
This error only happens when I plug a texture into the density input of a Principled Volume shader.

Comment: Hello, the volumetric settings are different between Eevee and Cycles, please post a screenshot of your settings, the node tree, etc :)

Comment: @Gorgious I have added my node setup and render settings

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the Principled Volume shader, turn the Blockbody Intensity down to zero.

It worked for me.

Comment: Please take a look at the information provided in the question before answering - including screenshots. Yes, he is using a _Principled Volume_ shader but the _Blackbody Intensity_ is already at 0.